# Translating C# async method to F# function

Tags: f#

I would like to translate the C# method DelayNe below to an F# function in such a way that it can be used from C# in exactly the same way. The reason is that I want to put it in an F# library. I am struggling a lot trying to google my way to an answer, with no luck obviously.

Update: Sorry for not being clear. I have tasks that call Task.Delay in the way that you see in the DelayNe method below. The problem is that when _cancellationTokenSource.Cancel() is called, then Task.Delay throws an exception, and I don't want that exception. In other words, I believe I need a wrapper around Task.Delay which will catch the exception and silence it, but otherwise expose the behavior of Task.Delay exactly as is. And I want to implement the wrapper in F#.

```
private CancellationTokenSource _cancellationTokenSource = new CancellationTokenSource();

async Task DelayNe(int milliSeconds, CancellationToken token)
{
    try
    {
        await Task.Delay(milliSeconds, token);
    }
    catch (TaskCanceledException ex)
    {
        ("Silencing " + ex.GetType().Name + ", " + ex.Message).Dump();
    }
}

async Task Test(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
{
    try
    {
        "Test start".Dump();
        await DelayNe(5000, cancellationToken);
        "Test stop".Dump();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        ("Catch: " + ex.Message + ", " + ex.GetType().Name).Dump();
    }
}

async Task Main()
{
    "Start".Dump();
    _cancellationTokenSource.CancelAfter(1000);
    var testTask = Test(_cancellationTokenSource.Token);
    await testTask;
    "Stop".Dump();
}
```

Comment: Before moving to F#, make sure the C# code is working. Right now it's broken - `async void` should only be used for *event handlers* because it can't be awaited. Furthermore, cold tasks are never needed. Don't use them in C#

Comment: Thanks. Changed from void to Task return from Test, and from new Task to Task.Factory.StartNew. But I still observe the same behavior in the output.

Comment: Why did you use StartNew? Why not just `await Test(cts.Token);`? Or store the return value ot `Test`, ie `var testTask = Test(_cancellationTokenSource.Token)`? It's already a Task.  `async` doesn't mean you need to start a task. It means that you *await* for an asynchronous operation like IO or calling a web service to complete, without blocking the current thread

Comment: Thanks again. Now the output is as expected.

Comment: Can the downvoter please explain what the problem is with this question?

Comment: I didn't downvote but there *is* a problem with this question. You ask how to translate something to F# when that something doesn't even work. You should be looking for tutorials on `async/await`. Things won't be easier if you switch to F#

Comment: I have switched to F# years ago, but still have legacy code in C#. That's why I stumble on these problems from time to time. There is an awful lot of options for exploiting multiple processors, and I simply can't prioritize to be an expert in all of them.

Comment: Tasks and async/await are equivalent to an `async` block

Answer (score 6, accepted):

F# asynchronous workflows have built-in support for cancellation, so using those instead of working with tasks will probably make your life a lot easier. Your question does not really provide enough information to understand what you are trying to do, but below is an example of using `async` for something that is very close to your example:

```
let delayNe ms = async {
  use! _d = Async.OnCancel(fun () -> 
    printfn "cancelled!")
  do! Async.Sleep(ms) }

let test = async {
  printfn "Test start"
  do! delayNe 5000
  printfn "Test stop" }

let DoWork () = 
  let cts = new System.Threading.CancellationTokenSource()
  cts.CancelAfter(1000)
  Async.StartAsTask(test, cancellationToken = cts.Token)
```

The `DoWork` function starts the work as a task, which can be easily consumed from C#.

Comment: In C# I want to do the equivalent of calling `await Task.Delay(ms, token);` so that I can abort the delay, but without having it throw the exception. So I want a wrapper for that, but implemented in F#. Thanks, I am trying to use this now.

Comment: `Async.Sleep` works well with the F# cancellation mechanism - it will not throw an exception and you can handle cancellation using `Async.OnCancel`. I suspect you are doing all this for some reason - so if you can share the reason, you might get a better advice.

Comment: Thanks, and I just added some explanation to the question.

Comment: I see - in that case, this should not be a problem in F#, because cancellation is not handled via ordinary exceptions :)